# WordPress Elementor API: render widget in custom php page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have created a custom woocommerce product page (not with Elementor). I would like to know if it is possible to render an Elementor widget in this custom page programmatically, without using the Elementor editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can - this is how:**

- Install "Anywhere Elementor" plugin (if you use Elementor free)
- Build your widget with Elementor
- Get your template php shortcode
- Edit your custom woocommerce product php template to echo out the widget
- In case you need more detail guide, i have similar a step by step
  guide video [here](https://youtu.be/esJV-L7qgso)